# Containers start with docker-compose up, are listed with docker ps, then don't appear with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've got an issue on ubuntu 18.04 where occasionally running `docker-compose up` results in the containers starting, the networking between them behaving as expected yet according to `docker-compose` they aren't there.

`docker ps` shows the containers exist.

UPDATE: after some comments:

`docker-compose ps` shows nothing. Also, the problem is intermittent meaning any example is hard to come by unfortunately.

Comment: What about `docker-compose ps` in the directory where the `docker-compose.yml` file is located ?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] – a sample Compose file, and the exact `docker` and `docker-compose` commands you're running?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see them in docker ps -a ? You should add `docker-compose -d up` for detached mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

`docker-compose ps`

from where your .yml file is located. It will show you the list of all docker containers generated from that .yml file